# React Router Works Locally, but Produces a Blank Page After Deployment on Vercel: How to Troubleshoot? Particularly the route with dynamic parameters

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, vercel

I'm facing a perplexing issue with deploying my React application using Vercel. Locally, my application works flawlessly with React Router, but after deploying it on Vercel, I'm encountering a blank page when trying to access specific routes, particularly the route involving dynamic parameters. (/projects/projet1 give me a blank page).

Here's a version of my routing setup:

```
<Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
     <Route path="*" element={<h1>NotFound</h1>} />
     <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
     <Route path="/projects/:slug" element={<Project />} />
     <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
</Routes>
```

I've double-checked the configuration, and the application works as expected in my local environment. The issue arises only when deployed to Vercel.

I've investigated potential solutions, including adding a vercel.json file, but the problem persists. I've also ensured that the necessary dependencies are correctly installed and that there are no console errors or warnings.

There is my vercel.json

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for all. Louis.

Comment: Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#vercel) for what you may need to configure for Vercel.

Comment: export default defineConfig({
  base: "./",
  plugins: [svgr(), react()],
})

The solution was to delete the Vite base !!!